# No Debug option for JIT Debugger in the application crash popup in Windows Vista/Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, windows-vista, debugging

I am debugging a native Win32 C++ Application. I am very much used to of using `DebugBreak()` to induce a crash and launch a JIT Debugger and attach with the Process.

Ever since i am moved to MS Vista i have lost this life saver. Need to get that 'debug' option back on thie application crash popup.

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio as Administrator, and check Tools>Options>Debugging>JIT>Native.

Comment: It's already checked, and VS2005 is indeed running as Administrator